# How avoid async method to use new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have read that await/async should not create/use new threads but the compiler creates a astate machien under the hood....so i tried this, and each call to F1 uses a thread from the ThreadPool.

```
class Program
{
    static System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim sem =
        new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(20, 20);
    static async void F1()
    {
        await sem.WaitAsync();
        await sem.WaitAsync();
        await Task.Delay(6000);
        var threadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        sem.Release();
        sem.Release();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

        F1();
        F1();
        F1();
        F1();
        F1();
        F1();
        F1();
        F1();
        Task.Delay(30000).Wait();
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

}
```

Comment: So where do you expect it to execute? It either runs on the current thread or on other threads (e.g. ThreadPool threads). Where else do you expect it to run?

Comment: In very specific cases if you really need to enter the same Synchronization Context, then there's a work around, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43977218/1559611), though its best to allow any thread pool thread to process, they are cheap and Async - Await is non blocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, i found the answer i was looking for.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Actually Mrinal Kamboj added a comment, to my question, pointing to the right direction. 
I needed to create a **synchronization context** for the continuations to run on. This snippet also shows why you should not Wait() on incomplete task: if the continuation runs on the same thread (which happens for GUI threads  or ASP.NET) , if this thread is locked waiting for continuation then we run in a dead-lock situation.

```
class Program
{
    static System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(3, 3);
    static async Task F(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"F{i} starts on " + GetCurrentThreadId());
        await Semaphore.WaitAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"F{i} continues on " + GetCurrentThreadId());
        await Task.Delay(6000);     //.ConfigureAwait(false); //<- uncomment to solve deadlock
        Console.WriteLine($"F{i} ends on " + GetCurrentThreadId());
        Semaphore.Release(1);
        //DeadLock();
    }

    static void DeadLock()
    {
        F(70).Wait();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int ind = i;
            F(ind);
        }
        context.RunOnCurrentThread();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

}


sealed class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{

    private readonly Thread Thread = Thread.CurrentThread;


    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (d == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("d");

        WorkItemsQueue.Add(new KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));
    }


    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Synchronously sending is not supported.");
    }


    public void RunOnCurrentThread()
    {
        foreach (var workItem in WorkItemsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            workItem.Key(workItem.Value);
    }


    public void Complete() { WorkItemsQueue.CompleteAdding(); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've used `await Task.Delay(6000)`, which is guaranteed to not complete synchronously, so: the completion will come back via whatever it can - typically the thread-pool (since there's no sync-context in play here). Thread pool threads are cheap as long as you don't tie them up for extended periods; if all it does is capture the current thread id and release, they should all be complete virtually immediately after they fire.

The code needs to run *somewhere*; what thread would you *expect it* to run on? Your main thread is currently in a blocking `Wait()` call, so it can't do anything. Note: you should almost never call `.Wait()` on an incomplete `Task`.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer to the original question.
Let's replace the Task.Delay with a call to retrive a web page...will they run on main thread? I guess they won't because the main thread will still be busy on wait() . Then how should i modify the code?

Comment: @N4rk0 what is "they" here? are you talking about the F1 continuations? No, they'll still run on the pool, and *that's OK*. What is making you think that there is a problem?

Comment: From this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx#BKMK_Threads:
"The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available."

Comment: @N4rk0 that doesn't say what you seem to suggest it says, though; any continuation needs to run *somewhere* when it completes, and that usually means either "pushed back via that sync-context" or "on the thread pool". The text is also accurate in that it did not create an additional thread for this purpose; that's the entire *purpose* of the thread pool. The key point here is that `Task.Delay` doesn't mean "block the current thread for this time"